# Removing punctuation from a list of strings that aren't part of a word

Tags: python, nlp

I am writing a program to detect collocations of bigrams (2 words that appear together more often than by chance, ex: hot dog). To do this properly, I have to remove all punctuation marks that would be stored as their own element but keep punctuations that are part of a word. For example, the bigram ['U.S. flag'] should keep the periods in U.S. but ['U.S. ,'] should have the comma removed. I've written a for loop that iterates through a list of punctuations and should remove the matching element, but that doesn't change anything. Additionally, I've used regex to remove most punctuations but if I remove periods then words with periods in them also get ruined. Any suggestions for an efficient way to remove these would be deeply appreciated!

Here's my code so far:

```
f = open('Collocations.txt').read()

punctuation = [',', '.', '!', '?', '"', ':', "'", ';', '@', '&', '$', '#', '*', '^', '%', '{', '}']
filteredf = re.sub(r'[,":@#?!&$%}{]', '', f)

f = f.split()

print(len(f))
for i, j in zip (punctuation, f):
    if i == j:
        ind = f.index(j)
        f.remove(f[ind])
print(len(f))


# removes first element in the temp list to prepare to make bigrams
temp = list()
temp2 = list()
temp  = filteredf.split()
temp2 = filteredf.split()
temp2.remove(temp2[0]) 

# forms a list of bigrams
bi = list()
for i, j in zip(temp, temp2):
    x = i + " " + j
    bi.append(x)
#print(len(bi))
unigrams = dict()
for i in temp:
    unigrams[i] = unigrams.get(i, 0) + 1 
#print(len(unigrams))



bigrams = dict()
for i in bi:
    bigrams[i] = bigrams.get(i, 0) + 1
#print(len(bigramenter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

replacing

```
for i, j in zip (punctuation, f):
    if i == j:
        ind = f.index(j)
        f.remove(f[ind])
```

with

```
while i < len(f)-2:
    c1 = f[i]
    c2 = f[i+1]
    c3 = f[i+2]
    if c2 in punctuation and not (c1 in string.ascii_letters and c3 in string.ascii_letters):
        f = f[:i+1] + f[i+2:]
    i+=1
```

Will preserve punctuation that has a letter on either side (e.g. U.S.A. will become U.S.A), however it seems to me that it would be impossible to tell the difference between the final period and a full stop e.g. U.S.A`.` and Hello`.`